# My makefile results in: No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed

Tags: makefile

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I wrote a simple hello world kernel module (`hello.c`). I wrote the folllowing makefile for it:

```
obj-m+=hello.o
KDIR:= /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
all:
     $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
     rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.* *.symvers *.order
```

But this error cropped up when I did make from kernel:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-24-generic-pae'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed
by `arch/x86/tools/relocs'.  Stop.
```

`hello.c` and `makefile` are in `/Documents/module_prog`. I ran `make` from that directory.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 13):

In the make file, just change `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` into `M=$(shell pwd)`...

Works like charm

Comment: `SUBDIRS=$(PWD)` does not exist in my make file

Answer (score 4):

**i386 headers required:**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r | sed 's/\(.*\)-[a-z]*/\1/'):i386
```

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-5.4.0-42:i386
```

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Someone help me out here please to understand what the problem is with this answer.

Comment: This actually solved my issue. I do not understand why people downvoted this

Comment: Find your kernel version with `uname -r`, cut out the "-generic" part.

Comment: Well simply because it doesn't work: `Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.0-81-generic:i386`

Comment: Try `linux-headers-5.4.0-81:i386` instead. Works here.

Answer (score 0):

to get headers files for your particular kernel... you may have more success with a slightly less clever version of @Thantelius answer:

```
apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt install <package name showing in the search>
```

however in most recent/major distros, headers should be installed by default

Answer (score 0):

After a long time with this problem, my solution was to rename the makefile from `makefile` to `Makefile`.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12686411/4424636) to [Should I name "makefile" or "Makefile"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12669367/4424636): *By default, when `make` looks for the makefile, it tries the following names, in order: `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` and `Makefile`.*

Comment: I tested both multiple times. It indeed only works with ‘Makefile’.