# Failed to build EVDI installing DisplayLink driver

Tags: drivers, dell, external-monitor, dkms, displaylink

I have a serious issue when installing a DispalyLink driver, specifically a Dell DA100 Adapter, on my Dell XPS 13 9360. I downloaded and unpacked the Displaylink driver from [the official website](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu).

Then I did `sudo displaylink-driver-1.3.54.run` and I got this:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 1.3.54  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 1.3.54 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/1.3.54. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/make.log for details..
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Please help me I need to make the adapter work to use my external monitor.

#### Update

[We have been working on this together with @EliahKagan.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/63705) I am posting here some major outputs that one could look at if encountering the same problem.

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux nyname-XPS-13-9360 4.4.0-91-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 8 11:56:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of `apt list --installed build-essential dkms\* gcc\* linux\*{generic,headers}\*`:

```
Elencazione... Fatto
build-essential/xenial,now 12.1ubuntu2 amd64 [installato]
dkms/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,now 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3 all [installato]
gcc/xenial,now 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installato]
gcc-4.4/xenial,now 4.4.7-8ubuntu7 amd64 [installato]
gcc-4.4-base/xenial,now 4.4.7-8ubuntu7 amd64 [installato, automatico]
gcc-4.8/xenial,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installato]
gcc-4.8-base/xenial,now 4.8.5-4ubuntu2 amd64 [installato, automatico]
gcc-4.9/xenial,now 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04 amd64 [installato]
gcc-4.9-base/xenial,now 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~16.04 amd64 [installato, automatico]
gcc-5/xenial,now 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04 amd64 [installato]
gcc-5-base/xenial,now 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04 amd64 [installato]
gcc-6/xenial,now 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04 amd64 [installato]
gcc-6-base/xenial,now 6.3.0-18ubuntu2~16.04 amd64 [installato]
gcc-7-base/xenial,now 7.1.0-5ubuntu2~16.04 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.91.96 amd64 [installato]
linux-headers-4.4.0-23/now 4.4.0-23.41 all [installato, locale]
linux-headers-4.4.0-23-generic/now 4.4.0-23.41 amd64 [installato, locale]
linux-headers-4.4.0-53/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-57/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-59/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-66/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-72/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-75/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-75.96 all [installato, automatico]
linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-75.96 amd64 [installato]
linux-headers-4.4.0-78/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-79/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-81/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-83/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-87/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 all [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-headers-4.4.0-89/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 all [installato, automatico]
linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-headers-4.4.0-91/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 all [installato, automatico]
linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-headers-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.91.96 amd64 [installato]
linux-image-4.4.0-23-generic/now 4.4.0-23.41 amd64 [installato, locale]
linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-75.96 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-23-generic/now 4.4.0-23.41 amd64 [installato, locale]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-75.96 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-89-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-91-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-image-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.91.96 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-signed-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.91.96 amd64 [installato]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-23-generic/now 4.4.0-23.41 amd64 [installato, locale]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-57-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-59-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-66-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-72-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-78-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-79-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-81-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-83-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-87-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-89-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-91-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-signed-image-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0.91.96 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-tools-4.4.0-23-generic/now 4.4.0-23.41 amd64 [installato, locale]
linux-tools-4.4.0-53-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-53.74 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-57-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-57.78 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-59-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-59.80 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-66-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-66.87 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-72-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-72.93 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-78-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-78.99 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-79-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-79.100 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-81-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-81.104 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-83-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-83.106 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-87-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-87.110 amd64 [installato, auto-rimovibile]
linux-tools-4.4.0-89-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-89.112 amd64 [installato, automatico]
linux-tools-4.4.0-91-generic/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 4.4.0-91.114 amd64 [installato, automatico]
```

Output of `type -a cc gcc`:

```
cc è /usr/bin/cc
gcc è /usr/bin/gcc
```

Output of `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.7-8ubuntu7) 4.4.7
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Output of `ls usr/bin/gcc*`:

```
/usr/bin/gcc      /usr/bin/gcc-4.8  /usr/bin/gcc-5  /usr/bin/gcc-ar      /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.9  /usr/bin/gcc-ar-6  /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.8  /usr/bin/gcc-nm-5  /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib      /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.9  /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-6
/usr/bin/gcc-4.4  /usr/bin/gcc-4.9  /usr/bin/gcc-6  /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.8  /usr/bin/gcc-ar-5    /usr/bin/gcc-nm    /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.9  /usr/bin/gcc-nm-6  /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.8  /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-5
```

The problem is that I have `gcc 4.4.7` and apparently DispalyLink needs at elast `gcc 4.9`. I solved by upgrading to `gcc6.3` and now the installation of the dirver is successfu, but the external monitor behaves very badly! It is extremely slow.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dkms status` and `cat /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.3.54/build/make.log`. Use copy/paste. Start new comments to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: The DisplayLink software is for 16.04, according to their web site, and you're running 16.04.2 which uses a newer kernel, so it may not compile correctly. I'd go to the Dell web site and see if they supply a newer driver for the DA100. Also use your service ID # to see if newer software is listed there for the DA100.

Comment: If it's okay with you, let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63705/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-johnhenry).

Answer (score 0):

Check here:

https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/215

[My makefile results in: No rule to make target `arch/x86/tools/relocs.c', needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232840/my-makefile-results-in-no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-tools-relocs-c-needed)

Same here, found the solution(replace `pwd` with `shell pwd`) or do `su && make` instead of `sudo make`, but cannot modify the "run" file because of the integrity check. Still digging. Also check here(maybe need to rebuild edvi myself):

https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/172